# A "Frankenstein's monster" similar metaphors

Tags: expressions, british-english, expression-choice, metaphors, poetry

Although originally it's a novel character, a "Frankenstein's monster" became a metaphor for *"something that cannot be controlled and that attacks or destroys the person who invented it."*
However, are there similar *"ruined by own creation"* metaphors or poetic expressions in British English?

Answer (score 1):

I think [dig one's own grave](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dig+own+grave) may suggest the idea:

> - Fig. to be responsible for one's own downfall or ruin.
> - to do something stupid that will cause problems for you in the future.
>
> If you try to cheat the bank, you will be digging your own grave. Those politicians have dug their own grave with their new tax bill. They won't be reelected.

Also : [shoot oneself in the foot](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+oneself+in+the+foot) :

> - Fig. to cause oneself difficulty; to be the author of one's own misfortune.
>
>   I am a master at shooting myself in the foot. Again, he shot himself in the foot by saying too much to the press.

Comment: Also my favourite, "hoist by your own petard". None of these quite have the "own *invention*" aspect in the way that "Frankenstein's monster" can.

Comment: I think they have, you have to be  inventive to create problems for yourself!!

Comment: The inventor of the petard getting hoisted by one is slightly different to someone else getting hoisted by one. That reminds me of this chap...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Midgley,_Jr.#Later_life_and_death

Comment: A wife who turns into a scolding, vicious woman (harridan--more common than you think): 'King Kong in bloomers'

Answer (score 1):

Asimov modified the Frankenstein theme when he introduced [**non-First Law robots**](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/2630345/3/untitled).

There's no modification of the term on this side of the Atlantic.